# Node.js ImageMagick working on one computer but not another

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make a Discord bot in discord.js with Node.js utilising ImageMagick, and I got it working perfectly on my computer--- problem is, when I migrate it to my Amazon server, it stops working. It should look like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0vGV.png)...

But instead, for some reason, it ends up looking more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bngYI.png), and I don't know why!

Here is my code:

```
var img = imageMagick().command("montage");
imgs.forEach(item => {img.in(item)});
img.in("-background","none")
    .in("-tile","4x2")
    .in("-geometry",bg ? "40x40+4+4" : "70x70+0+0");
img.write(this.filename, function(err){
    var exThis = getImgRefFromOutName(this.outname);
    if (!exThis.bg) {
        img = imageMagick().command("convert")
            .in(exThis.filename);
        if (exThis.imgs.length <= 4) img.in("-trim");
    } else if (exThis.bg) {
        img = imageMagick().command("composite")
            .in("-geometry","+32+60")
            .in(exThis.filename)
            .in(bg);
    }
    img.write(exThis.filename, function(err){
        var exThis = getImgRefFromOutName(this.outname);
        exThis.status++;
        exThis.upload();
    });
});
```

It doesn't change between computers, so something else must be the problem. Any idea what it could be? I've uninstalled and reinstalled ImageMagick and all the Node modules several times.

Comment: I'd suggest you check the version numbers and upgrade anything older than v6.9.

Comment: imageMagick is version 7.0.7, Node.js is version 8.11.2, discord.js is version 11.3.2, ImageMagick module for Node is the latest version

Comment: Normally, you start with an input image, or two. then you do something and end up with an output image. What are you showing us? The result? If so, what's the input? Or are showing us the input image(s)? Please clarify in English, what you start with, what you are trying to do, and the result you have as well as what you were expecting. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. Apologies, the initial post was rushed.
Basically, I had an array of images like [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/350455858066620418/447492429327630357/114.png), and I had them all turned into a montage; then, I wrote that montage to file, and composited it onto [this background](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/350455858066620418/447492371417137163/court_record.png).
It _should_ look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0vGV.png)-- and it does, on my computer-- but when I add it to my Amazon server, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bngYI.png).

Comment: Have you installed imageMagick on the remote server?

Comment: I most definitely have.

Comment: Update: I just tested the arguments I've put in on both the remote server and my own computer, and they're the exact same. I've also run both the commands via command line and they work on both computers, however the problem arises when I try to run them via Node.js. I'm thinking this must be a problem with Node.js...

Comment: Another update: I made sure all of my Node.js files were exactly the same on both computers. It still is not working. I don't know _what_ could be the problem.